# locationManager.requestLocationUpdates() results in NullpointerException

Tags: android, android-intent

what i want to do is a Service that i can start. When i start the service it should listen for gps location updates. so i implemented the following service:

```
public class TrackingService extends Service {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected PendingIntent locationReceiverPendingIntent;
    protected Intent locationIntent;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        locationIntent = new Intent(this, LocationReceiver.class);
        locationReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, locationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE); // FINE tries to use GPS

        long minimumWaitBetweenLocationUpdatesInMilliSeconds = 15000;
        float minimumLoctaionChangeInMeters = 50;
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(minimumWaitBetweenLocationUpdatesInMilliSeconds, minimumLoctaionChangeInMeters, criteria, locationReceiverPendingIntent);    
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationReceiverPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I start this service in my starting activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, TrackingService.class);     
    this.startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

LocationReceiver is a BroadcastReceiver. I get the following NullPointerExpection on the line with the following code `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(minimumWaitBetweenLocationUpdatesInMilliSeconds, minimumLoctaionChangeInMeters, criteria, locationReceiverPendingIntent);`:

> VM does not provide monitor information
>   Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))        
>     ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread$CreateServiceData)
>   line: 2539        ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread,
>   ActivityThread$CreateServiceData) line: 141
>     ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1316
>     ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
>     Looper.loop() line: 137     ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5041
>     Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native method]      Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 511      ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 793
>     ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 560     NativeStart.main(String[])
>   line: not available [native method]

What could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize locationManager

```
locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(minimumWaitBetweenLocationUpdatesInMilliSeconds, minimumLoctaionChangeInMeters, criteria, locationReceiverPendingIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for this hint. Don't know how i managed to oversee that :D